# How to type condensed formulas in ChemDraw?

Tags: software, notation

What I want is shown in the bubble 1, while what I keep getting every time I change the single bond to a double bond is shown in bubble 2. The H of the middle C in bubble 2 keeps shifting down when I want it to be in line with the C like in bubble 1. How do I do this in ChemDraw?

[image]

Comment: I have moved it from the meta site (https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/ which is for discussions about the site) to the main site (https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/). I personally would say it is on topic here, but others might disagree. I do not know whether there is a user forum for ChemDraw, where this would be more suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly simple to do.

1. Select the atom you want to change.
2. Right-click > Alignment > choose anything *but* "Automatic"

You will have to twiddle with the bond lengths to make it look ok. According to [*Graphical Representation Standards for Chemical Structure Diagrams (IUPAC Recommendations 2008)*](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277),

> On atoms with two attached bonds, an atom label should be oriented to minimize its overlap with any bonds in the structure. The label may be stacked vertically above or below, or may not be stacked at all depending on the orientation of the two bonds.
>
> [image: Examples of unacceptable horizontal atom labels]

Comment: Thank you. Also, I don't think the fiddling with the bond lengths will be too cumbersome. The structures I made are at most four carbons long and that is when I explicitly label the atoms.

Comment: Also how can I numerically edit specific bond lengths? I can't find the option anywhere.

Comment: @SillysackButtowski Select the bond(s) and the two atoms surrounding them. Then click on the Object menu > Object Settings > Drawing and change the number under "Fixed Length".